# Can't call kotlin function with varargs from java

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to pass **two** parameters as `varargs` (**typesList** and **operationStatus**).
Here code:

```
fun getOperationsList(
        vararg typesList: OperationType,
        operationStatus: OperationStatus,
        from: Date, to: Date,
        callback: Callback<List<Operation>>
    ) {
```

I need call this from java code:

Here java code:

```
Date[] selectedPeriod = getSelectedPeriod();
        TransportService.INSTANCE.getOperationsList(new OperationType[]{OperationType.PAYMENT, OperationType.PAYOUT}
                , new OperationStatus[]{OperationStatus.EXECUTED, OperationStatus.CREATED}, selectedPeriod[0], selectedPeriod[1],
```

But I get compile error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type. Found: 'OperationStatus[]', required: 'OperationStat
```

Comment: Looks like you need `vararg typesList: Array<OperationType>`

Comment: You passing array of `OperationStatus`, but the function accepts Object of `OperationStatus`. Two parameters as `vararg` not possible

Replace `operationStatus: OperationStatus` with this `operationStatus: Array<OperationStatus>`

Answer (score 4):

> I need to pass two parameters as `vararg`

It's not possible. According to [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html)

> Only one parameter may be marked as vararg

Also, `vararg` parameter should be the last one in the function declaration. Or addressed as a named parameter (by name).

> If a vararg parameter is not the last one in the list, values for the following parameters can be passed using the named argument syntax

Answer (score -2):

instead of passing array of OperationStatus try passing object of OperationStatus